# Prevent losing my iPhone

Tags: iphone, airtag

I saw an article about preventing loss of your iPhone, but it required that you have an Apple Watch or laptop that you carry with you.

I wonder, can this work:
Get an AirTag, keep in always with me.  Then program the iPhone and AirTag so that when they are far apart, the AirTag will alert me of that.  So, when I walk out leaving my iPhone behind, the AirTag tells me.

AirTags normally work when I have my iPhone with me and the AirTag is lost.  Can it be done in reverse like this?

Comment: What stops you from using find my with your Apple ID? You can login to your Apple ID from any desktop Browser.

Comment: @X_841 True.  But I want to be notified when I walk out the door, even if I am not carrying a desktop browser.

Comment: What will ensure you don’t lose the watch first?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the AirTag notify you when it loses connection to the phone in the manner you are describing.

You can only have your phone notify you when it loses connection to the AirTag.

Comment: That's, aside from technical limitations, to avoid an entire carousel of airport luggage all beeping away ;)